Error in My Alternative Solution to a Conditional Probability Problem
I was trying to solve the practice question below:
Question:
A man possesses five coins, two of which are double-headed, one is double-tailed, and two are normal. He shuts his eyes, picks a coin at random, and tosses it. He opens his eyes and sees that the coin is showing heads; what is the probability that the lower face is a head?
The Correct Answer is provided in the image below for (ii):

I tried an alternative solution but my answer does not match the given correct answer. What is the problem with my approach ?
My Wrong Solution:
$\sum_{Chosen\ Coin\ \in\ \{M, R, N\}}{P(H_l|Chosen\ Coin)\ P(Chosen\ Coin | H_{u})} = \sum_{Chosen\ Coin\ \in\ \{M, R, N\}}{P(H_l, Chosen\ Coin|H_u)} = P(H_l | H_u) = \sum_{Chosen\ Coin\ \in\ \{M, R, N\}}{P(H_l|Chosen\ Coin)\ P(Chosen\ Coin | H_{u})} = 1 * \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} * \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{3}{4}$
which yields the wrong answer.
Thank you.

Hi, please give definitions of each term you are using. What is "Every Coins"? What is "Chosen Coin"? What is $H_l$? What is $H_u$?

Hi, $H_l$ and $H_u$ correspond to the events that the lower face of the coin is a head, and the upper face of the coin is a head respectively. Their definitions were provided in the explanation of the correct answer. I also clarified the definition of the Chosen Coin further via the math notation.

Thanks. Is there an unfinished equation? There's an equals sign with nothing on the right of it.

The right side of the equal sign is just the equations wrapping to the line below. I guess they did not fit.

There are two issues with your calculations:

If you have a normal coin and its upper side is heads then its lower side is definitely tails.  Your sum should have been

$$P(H_l\mid H_u)=\sum_{Chosen\ Coin\ \in\ \{HH, HT, TT\}}{P(H_l\mid Chosen\ Coin, H_{u})\ P(Chosen\ Coin \mid H_{u})}$$

Your calculation of the probability of having chosen a double headed coin given the upper side is heads contains an error and it should be $\frac23$ instead of $\frac12$ (and similarly of having chosen a normal coin given the upper side is heads should be $\frac13)$ :

$$(Chosen\ Coin_{HH} | H_{u}) = \tfrac{P(Chosen\ Coin_{HH} \cap H_{u})}{P(Chosen\ Coin_{HH} \cap H_{u})+P(Chosen\ Coin_{HT} \cap H_{u})+P(Chosen\ Coin_{TT} \cap H_{u})}$$ $$=\dfrac{\frac25 \times \frac22}{\frac25 \times \frac22+\frac25 \times \frac12+\frac15 \times \frac02}=\dfrac23.$$
Correcting both these would make your calculation $1\times \dfrac23+ 0 \times \dfrac13=\dfrac23.$
Another route to the same answer is to say there are $6$ heads and $4$ tails in the experiment, each equally likely to be seen on the upper side.  Of the $6$ heads, $4$ have heads on the lower side, so the conditional probability is $\frac46=\frac23$.
